# Website URL mapping from ASP.Net URL to MVC URL to redirect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

We would like to redirect users from below URL

http://mywebsite.com/Account.asp?Number=25191108

To

http://anotherwebsite.com/Account/25191108

Please let me know if we can do it by config at IIS level or in web.config

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL Rewrite module in IIS to achieve this. You can install it from [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).
Add the following rule in your web.config file under "system.webServer" tag.

Let me know if it breaks or if you have any questions around this.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="sample2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*).asp(.*)Number=(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://anotherWebsite.com/{R:1}/{R:3}" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```